# Pasar texto de mayúsculas a Capitalize CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Les cuento mi problema,

Necesito pasar a capitalize un texto que está en mayúsculas, he utilizado la propiedad

`.info p{ text-transform: capitalize}`

Mi problema es que con las minúsculas que aparecen en el texto funciona perfecto. pero no afecta a las mayúsculas.

o tendré que hacerlo con js?

Comment: Cabe destacar que es por que estás usando mal `capitalize`. La función de `capitalize` es `transformar el primer carácter de cada palabra a mayúsculas`. Si dicha letra ya estaba en mayúsculas, no hará nada. Y tampoco hace contacto alguno con el resto de la palabra. Por eso, y como @Triby lo ha hecho, hay que realmente convertir el texto a minúsculas, antes de capitalizar.

Comment: Quieres que cada palabra está capitalizada o solo la primer letra del párrafo/contenido? si fuera solo la primer letra de la primer palabra si es viable con CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, a menos que alguien proporcione otra solución, debes usar Javascript:

1. Obtener todos los párrafos con `document.querySelectorAll()` especificando la clase a la que pertenecen
2. Recorrer con `forEach()` para convertir a minúsculas
3. La clase CSS se encarga de capitalizar el resultado

```js
// Obtener todos los párrafos dentro de contenedores con clase .info
// Recorrer (forEach)
document.querySelectorAll('.info p').forEach(p => {
  // Convertir a minúsculas
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.toLowerCase()
});
```

```css
.info p {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <p>TEXTO A CAPITALIZAR con MAYÚSCULAS y minúsculas.</p>
</div>
```